# How to set one foreign key references multiple primary keys in EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework, data-annotations, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I use code-first approach. I want to use just `ObjectId` property in `ObjectScore` as foreign key for three relations with `Professor` (Id) , `College` (Id) and `EducationalGroup` (Id), like what's happening at SQL

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectScore_Colege] FOREIGN KEY([ObjectId])
CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectScore_Professer] FOREIGN KEY([ObjectId])
CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectScore_EducationGroup] FOREIGN KEY([ObjectId])
```

How to make this relation in Entity Framework (data annotations or fluent api)?

Thanks all

```
public class Professor : Person
{
    public int ProfessorCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EducationalGroup> EducationalGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<College> Colleges { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectScore> ObjectScores { get; set; }
}

public class College : BaseClass
{
   public int CollegeCode { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Professor> Professors { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<EducationalGroup> EducationalGroups { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ObjectScore> ObjectScores { get; set; }
}

public class EducationalGroup : BaseClass
{
    public int CollegeCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Professor> Professors { get; set; }
    public virtual College College { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectScore> ObjectScores { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectScore
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int CurrentScore { get; set; }

    public virtual Term Term { get; set; }
    public virtual Score Score { get; set; }

    public int ObjectId { get; set; }    
}
```

and my `BaseClass` and `Person` classes:

```
public class Person : BaseClass
{
   public string Family { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        IsActive = false;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you mean that if a professor, EducationalGroup and a college have the same Id (PK) they will automatically get the same Scores ?

Comment: No,I have an property at Score that is a distinguishing factor for classes(ObjectTypeId).